# ES2015 Promise chains - why is the promisified function run immediately?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following print `2 1 3` instead of `1 2 3` as I expected?

```js
(function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    document.write('2');
    resolve();
  })
  .then(log('1')); // I was expecting this `log` function invocation to run first
}());

function log(message) {
  document.write(message);

  return function() {
    document.write('3');
  }
}
```

I am using Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m.

Comment: The executor function will be executed first. The result that you are seeing is correct as per your code.

Comment: Why do you think `2 1 3` isn't correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

> The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise implementation which provides the resolve and reject functions (the executor is called before the Promise constructor even returns the created object).

Your initial anonymous function runs, and inside it the `new Promise()` call runs, and the first thing that does is run your executor function (the callback to the constructor). *That*, in turn, immediately calls `document.write(2)`, so the first thing you see is `2`.

*edit* — seeing the clarification in your question, it boils down to simple JavaScript invocation order. Your Promise-constructing function contains just that `return` statement, which has the form:

```
return new C(fn).then(expr);
```

JavaScript completes the `new C(fn)` call before it starts work on the rest of the expression. Once the `new` returns (at which time the `2` will have already been printed), the `.then(expr)` part of the expression is evaluated. That'll trigger the printing of `1` via the `log()` call in the argument list of `.then()`.

The left-hand side of the `.` operator has to be completely evaluated first, because otherwise there's no place to look up the "then" property.